# TV series about a man from another world, using an object to control things

Tags: story-identification, tv

As a little boy I really liked a TV series about a man from outer space (at least I think it was) who had this metallic object/sphere that he could use to control different things with (possibly levitate things, control his ship, etc).

But since it was so long ago, I'm afraid this is all I have - does anyone know what it could be?

Comment: When were you a little boy?

Comment: Book series? TV series? Movie series? Radio series? Comic book series?

Comment: @phantom42 - I assumed TV series.

Comment: Downvote will be removed when this question is not so vague.

Comment: Ummm... closest that comes to mind at the moment is a film called [Starman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088172/) - but that wouldn't be a "series"... (and I don't think they were metallic objects)

Comment: @JonClements yes there is a [serie](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starman_(TV_series)) based on the movie Starman.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria oh good find... now it's been mentioned - I remember seeing that series... Wow... what memories flooding back... I'd be curious if that's not the correct answer for the OP - then what is :)

Comment: I watched Starman the series without having seen the movie first. This description was instantly recognizable. The show was like The Incredible Hulk if you substitute "holds a metal sphere in his hand until it glows" for "gets mad and turns into Lou Ferrigno"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're referring to the TV series [*Starman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starman_(TV_series)), not to be confused with the movie of the same name.

The titular character and his son both used luminous metallic balls to control their spaceship, to levitate and to communicate telepathically.

[image: Cut from a poster showing a teenage boy in a denim jacket looking at one of the luminous balls in his hand which is held in front of his dead in a white shirt and dark jacket. We can see the Earth in the background]

Comment: This is it! :-D Thank you

Comment: Credit is also due to @JonClements for reminding me of "Starman"

Answer (score -1):

In the *Galaxy Rangers*, Galaxy Green (played by [Reggie Rolle](https://powerrangers.fandom.com/wiki/Reggie_Rolle)) had a Megazord sphere that he could use to control the ship and other things.

[image: Image of the prop: a green sphere with silver stripes on the 4 "sides" with gold outlines and a hollow top: two discs/lids sit next to it, they are circular with a gold detailed outer and a green insert in the centre with symbols on]

Comment: Could you define this answer a little more.